# GetListUsingItems with Tridion Core Service returns more items than TOM

Tags: tridion

I want to get all children of a Blueprint item using the GetListUsingItems approach with the Tridion Core Service.  I get back different results (more) with the Core Service than with the old way in TOM.  It appears I also get back other Components referencing my source Component via a Component Link.  Am I missing a filter option in the Core Service?

Tridion 5.3:

```
Function GetLocalizedItemNodes(itemUri)
    Dim tridionItem : set tridionItem = tdse.GetObject(itemUri,1) 
    Dim rowFilter : set rowFilter = tdse.CreateListRowFilter()
    call rowFilter.SetCondition("ItemType", GetItemType(itemUri))
    call rowFilter.SetCondition("InclLocalCopies", true)
    Dim usingItemsXml : usingItemsXml = tridionItem.Info.GetListUsingItems(1919, rowFilter)

    Dim domDoc : set domDoc = GetNewDOMDocument()  
    domDoc.LoadXml(usingItemsXml)
    Dim nodeList : set nodeList = domDoc.SelectNodes("/tcm:ListUsingItems/tcm:Item[@CommentToken='LocalCopy']")

    set tridionItem = nothing
    set domDoc = nothing
    set GetLocalizedItemNodes = nodeList
End Function
```

Tridion 2011 SP1 Core Service:

```
   private XElement GetLocalizedItems(string itemUri)
    {
        XElement usingXML = null;
        try
        {
            CoreServiceClient client = new CoreServiceClient();
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["impersonationUser"].ToString(); // "administrator";
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["impersonationPassword"].ToString();
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["impersonationDomain"].ToString();

            // original code from http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/getting-used-items-using-the-core-service
            // Create a filter
            UsingItemsFilterData usingItemsFilterData = new UsingItemsFilterData
            {
                BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.IdAndTitle, // to specify the detail in the XML
                IncludeLocalCopies = true,
                ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Component }
            };
            // Get the XML by calling .GetListXml on the client (assumes you have a 'client' object already)
            usingXML = client.GetListXml(itemUri, usingItemsFilterData);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return usingXML;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Robert.  It should not affect the number of Components that you are getting back (as your source item is a Component), but it might be worth noting that your R5.3 code sets an 'ItemType' row filter (meaning that you will only get Components back) but your Core Service code doesn't.  This may affect your total number of results, but not the amount of Components (as you describe).

Comment: I added the ItemTypes condition but still get the related Components and children as well.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use **BluePrintChainFilterData** :

```
BluePrintChainFilterData filter = new BluePrintChainFilterData();
filter.Direction = BluePrintChainDirection.Down;
var result = ClientAdmin.GetListXml("tcm:3-1905", filter);
```

Please note that you can specify **Direction** property. This filter, however will not show you shared items. Also, try to avoid using UsingItemsFilterData as it is heavy on database

If you want to include shared items as well, then you can use **BluePrintFilterData**:

```
BluePrintFilterData filter = new BluePrintFilterData();
filter.ForItem = new LinkToRepositoryLocalObjectData{ IdRef = "tcm:3-1905"};
var listXml = ClientAdmin.GetSystemWideListXml(filter);
var list = ClientAdmin.GetSystemWideList(filter);
```

You can specify *ForItem* property here to set your item. It will return you something like this:

```
<tcm:ListBluePrintNodes Managed="1" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <tcm:BluePrintNode ID="tcm:0-3-1" Title="Test" Icon="T1L0P0">
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:3-1905" Title="Test multimedia component" ItemType="16" IsShared="False" IsLocalized="False" IsPublished="False" LockType="0" LockUser="tcm:0-0-0" Icon="T16L0P0Mgif"></tcm:Item>
  </tcm:BluePrintNode>
  <tcm:BluePrintNode ID="tcm:0-172-1" Title="test_child" Icon="T1L0P0">
    <tcm:Parents>
      <tcm:Parent xlink:href="tcm:0-3-1" xlink:title="Test" Priority="1"></tcm:Parent>
    </tcm:Parents>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:172-1905" Title="Test multimedia component" ItemType="16" IsShared="True" IsLocalized="False" IsPublished="False" LockType="0" LockUser="tcm:0-0-0" Icon="T16L0P0Mgif"></tcm:Item>
  </tcm:BluePrintNode>
</tcm:ListBluePrintNodes>
```

The good thing about system wide list is that you can use **GetSystemWideList** method that will return you array of **BluePrintNodeData** objects instead of XML

Comment: Awesome answer!  Thanks for providing 2 examples and the great explanation.