# Third Party application connecting to tridion using Core Service 2011

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am new to Tridion , so finding it difficult to get the starting point on how to connect to tridion server through Thrid party application using Core Service.

Can any one share some code of .NET application which sends request to tridion for creating component in tridion server.

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Janu. You'll find that people here are quite helpful and even more so when you first do some basic googling and experimenting yourself, before asking for sample code. Read this great post: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of good blog posts and sample applications out there. A single [search gives me these results](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=tridion+core+service):

- [Robert Curlette documented his first console app that uses the Core Service](http://www.curlette.com/?p=570)
- [GetListUsingItems with Tridion Core Service returns more items than TOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515647/getlistusingitems-with-tridion-core-service-returns-more-items-than-tom)
- [Get Core Service Client without config file](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/GetCoreServiceClientWithoutConfigFile)
- [SDL Tridion 2011 Component Publisher](http://blog.building-blocks.com/sdl-tridion-2011-component-publisher)
- [Importing Content using the Core Service in SDL Tridion 2011](http://blog.building-blocks.com/creating-custom-pages-using-the-core-service-in-sdl-tridion-2011)
- [Getting used items using the core service](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/getting-used-items-using-the-core-service)
- [SDL Tridion 2011 AppData](http://tridionfanboy.wordpress.com/category/sdl-tridion/2011/core-service-2011/)
- [Core Service Client Sample Code](http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/core-service-client-sample-code.html)

And of course the official documentation (requires login):

- [Getting the .NET client up and running](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_B49EC308F06D48E19230A2EC6070E14E)